# getting a control from the viewModel

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, parent-child

in my viewModel I can get the window associated with it using

```
var windows = Application.Current.Windows;
            for (var i = 0; i < windows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (windows[i].DataContext == this)
                {
                   //                      
                }
            }
```

there is a FlowDocument in  this window that I need a reference to it here in my viewModel, I know I can sometime break the rules and write some code-behind , but since I have the window and this control is contained/child in/of this window I thought I can get it done without aany code-behind , any suggesstions ?

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you need the control for? Perhaps there is another way you can do what you are trying to accomplish without referencing the ViewModel

Comment: There is not a rule to eliminate all code in the code-behind when using MVVM.  The rule is "Only have UI code in the UI object". If you need to manipulate the UI and you can't do it in XAML, code-behind is the proper place to put it.

Comment: @Rachel I need the FlowDocument to convert it to an XPS document and attach it to a MailMessage and send it all together on the fly,I don't think I can't but to have a reference the FlowDocument

Comment: @Rhyous agree, I know by referencing any control in my ViewModel I'm not using MVVM the right way, however in this particular task I believe that I have to , just for code clarification I prefer to have a clean code-behind

Comment: @Musaab Couldn't your FlowDocument's Content be bound to a property in your ViewModel? Then to send, you would just send the bound value as the MailMessage body.

Comment: I thought about that too , but my client like the XPS idea more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, you're not using MVVM the right way if you need access to UI elements in the ViewModel. You should consider using bindings for this instead (whatever it is that you're doing:-)

Anyway, you can traverse the visual tree to find descendants of the `Window`. However the `FlowDocument` isn't in the visual tree as it is a `FrameworkContentElement` so `VisualTreeHelper` won't work.

You'll need to combine `VisualTreeHelper` and `LogicalTreeHelper`: An implementation of this can be found here: [Find Element By Visual Tree](https://sites.google.com/site/bobstechwiki/home/wpf-ji-shu-1/find-element-by-visual-tree)

Here is a slightly rewritten version of it, use it like

```
if (windows[i].DataContext == this)
{
    var flowDocument = windows[i].FindChild<FlowDocument>();
}
```

**DependencyObjectExtensions.cs**

```
public static class DependencyObjectExtensions
{
    public static T FindChild<T>(this DependencyObject source) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (source != null)
        {
            var childs = GetChildObjects(source);
            foreach (DependencyObject child in childs)
            {
                //analyze if children match the requested type
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    return (T)child;
                }

                T descendant = FindChild<T>(child);
                if (descendant is T)
                {
                    return descendant;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetChildObjects(this DependencyObject parent)
    {
        if (parent == null) yield break;

        if (parent is ContentElement || parent is FrameworkElement)
        {
            //use the logical tree for content / framework elements
            foreach (object obj in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(parent))
            {
                var depObj = obj as DependencyObject;
                if (depObj != null) yield return (DependencyObject)obj;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //use the visual tree per default
            int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                yield return VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thats did the trick , thanks , I agree that I'm not doing MVVM right in this particular task , would be GREAT to know if it is possible to do this MVVM way , converting a FlowDocument with data-bind elements to an XPS document ,here I'm not interested in the control properties, actually I'm interested in the control itself.